# Tornado Request Handler

Tags: python, class, request, tornado, setcookie

For some reason i am unable to instantiate the set_cookie outside of the MainHandler..
This is a little code to show what im wanting to do..
Can Anyone help??

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
from tornado.options import define, options
from GenCookie import * 

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
       g=GenCookie()
       response = g.genCookie()

class GenCookie:
 def genCookie(self):
    print self.request.remote_ip
    print self.cookies
    print self.request.headers
    expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
    if ("uid" in cookies):
       self.set_cookie("uid", value=cookies["uid"],expires=expires)
    else:
       self.set_cookie("uid", value='dfc278623ab44df2bd501e106e81d146',expires=expires)
    return
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I thought that explains itself.

set_cookie is a method of tornado.web.RequestHandler

while in your code "self.set_cookie", self refers to object of class GenCookie.

Your code can be modified to pass the necessary reference

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
       g=GenCookie(self)
       response = g.genCookie()

class GenCookie:
 def __init__(self, reqHandler):
    self.reqHandler = reqHandler

 def genCookie(self):
    print self.request.remote_ip
    print self.cookies
    print self.request.headers
    expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
    if ("uid" in self.cookies):
       self.reqHandler.set_cookie("uid", value=self.cookies["uid"],expires=expires)
    else:
       self.reqHandler.set_cookie("uid", value='dfc278623ab44df2bd501e106e81d146',expires=expires)
    return
```